# "Os { code: 10060, kind: TimedOut" when in headers Connection: keep-alive

Tags: rust

I have some issue with TcpStream, when i send "Connection: close" all works fine, when i send "Connection: keep-alive" i get TimedOut error(but in wireshark i get response very fast)

Code:

```
use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpStream};
use std::str::from_utf8;
use std::time::Duration;

let ip_port="api.ipify.org:80";
let data=b"GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.ipify.org\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\n";
match TcpStream::connect(ip_port){
    Ok(mut tcp)=>{
        match tcp.write_all(data){
            Ok(_)=>{
                tcp.set_read_timeout(Some(Duration::from_secs(2))).unwrap();
                let mut buf = Vec::new();
                match tcp.read_to_end(&mut buf){
                    Ok(_)=>{
                        println!("{:?}", from_utf8(&buf));
                    },
                    Err(e)=>{
                        println!("ERR read{:?}", e);
                    }
                }
            },
            Err(e)=>{
                println!("ERR write:{:?}", e);
            }
        }
    }
    Err(e)=>{
        println!("ERR connect{:?}", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? `keep-alive` literally means to keep the TCP collection alive, a.k.a. to not close it. So, `read_to_end` will never terminate and will timeout since there is no end to read to.

Comment: use a proper http lib, tcp is not for beginner and ... HTTP either but for other reason